# Dependência não é adicionada ao projeto clojure

Tags: java, programação-funcional, clojure

Estou aprendendo Clojure e criei um projeto simples de spellchecker. Neste projeto, eu gostaria de usar a classe StringUtils do Apache Commons, para isso adicionei as seguintes linhas de código para importá-la em meu projeto.

```
; arquivo core.clj -- contém o método main
(ns spellchecker.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
  (:import (org.apache.commons.langr StringUtils)))


; arquivo project.clj -- contém as dependências
(defproject spellchecker "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "simple spell checker"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                [org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 "3.3.2"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot spellchecker.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

No ententanto, quando executo o comando `lein run` dentro do diretório do meu projeto. recebo o erro: `CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.langr.StringUtils, compiling:(/home/leonardo/clojure-learning/spellchecker/src/spellchecker/core.clj:1:1)` que diz basicamente que a dependência não foi baixada. Como posso baixar as dependências antes ou quando executo o projeto?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é o nome incorreto do pacote no arquivo `core.clj`.

Para resolver, substitua

```
(:import (org.apache.commons.langr StringUtils)))
```

por

```
(:import (org.apache.commons.lang3 StringUtils)))
```